# Making your PHP website into SAML Identity Provider

Tags: php, zend-framework, saml

Story is that I need to make my website act as Identity Provider (read: IDP). Website itself is on Zend platform. Idea is making a IDP controller by which Service Providers (read: SP) contacts IDP. As it must be part of the website, I would need to include some extension, which could be easily used for responding SAML requests from SP.

I have found list of PHP extensions from:
https://wiki.surfnetlabs.nl/display/OSP/RFC+-+OpenSAMLphp,+a+new+PHP+library+for+SAML+2.0+support

All of these extensions have little documentation or are too complex. For example I haven't found a way to use SimpleSamlPHP in my application and also extracting useful code out of it looks very time consuming (which I really don't have anymore). Also I find all of them hard to implement **into** website.

I have been googling and checking github for days now, trying to find easy way to use some library (right now I'm trying to implement Lasso, which seems reasonable, but unfortunately lacks good examples / information how to use it as IDP).

Any kind of criticism, ideas, help or tutorial/code examples would be useful.

Comment: I am stuck in same requirement and searching for the solution.I want to know if there is any efficient solution for the same. ?

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a guide about how deploy on an open source software (Tiki-wiki) an IdP using simplesamlphp, and how to connect the IdP to google or salesforce. Take a look:

https://github.com/pitbulk/tiki-saml/blob/master/doc/tiki_wiki_as_idp.rst

Comment: This is one of the best guides so far. I would give +1 for useful, but not enough points. But your example is meant as standalone service and would reside outside my website, which doesn't fulfill my goal.

What I want is my SP (http://spService.com) to contact http://myService.com/sso and "ask is this user logged in your site?". After response, SP would check if Valid, then log in - otherwise ask credentials and with logging into spService, it does not need to login into myService.com!

Comment: My suggestion: 

Deploy one SP for spService.com and other SP for myService.com.

This last SP (myService.com), will act also as an IdP, where the auth backend is the database of the myService.com

Then connect all the components.

Comment: Definitely a useful guide. You should blog it somewhere so perhaps Google will pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleSAMLphp seems intimidating at first but it can handle all the SAML responses for you. 
Have you looked at creating custom authentication module - http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-customauth

You can tie this module to your existing login mechanism pretty easily.

Comment: Well, but how can you use it in your website application? How do I construct my SimpleSamlPHP and send my SP request to that library, when it's not seperate domain ? For example: 
$saml = new SamlAbstract($xml, $token, $spDomain); // constructs my saml, then goes to SimpleSamlPHP to do all authentication process 
$saml->sendResponse(); // sends response to SP (in metadata it should say valid or invalid right?)

Answer (score 1):

Check out PingFederate and the PHP Integration Kit from Ping Identity. Alternatively there is the Agentless Integration Kit (instead of PHP) which allows you to integrate using a RESTful API call to the PingFed server instead of embedding any PHP libraries.

HTH,
Ian

Comment: PingFederate is a seperate commercial server and PHP integration Kit by their information is for PingFederate - which does not work out for me as I don't want to make another VirtualHost into httpd.conf and I need all SAML IDP to be done in my website. But thanks for advice.

Comment: Understood. Quick clarification though -- PF has its own built in HTTP(S) server so you would not add anything to your httpd.conf file to setup a virtual server.